# How to extend a variable outside a multi-threaded while loop

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a shell script that contains a multi-threaded while loop. My loop iterates through the values of an array. Within the loop, I am calling a function. At the end of the function I am saving the results as a string variable. I want to add this string variable to an array on each iteration, and then be able to retrieve the contents of this array when the while loop completes.

From my understanding running the multi-threaded while loop, is what is causing for the array to be empty once the while loop completes. Each thread is ran in its own environment and the array value does not extend outside that environment. I would like to be able to extend this array value outside of the thread if possible. Currently I am just writing the string value to a temp file and then after the while loop, reading the contents of the temp file and saving that as my array. This method works, as the file generally isn't "too" large, but I would like to avoid writing to file if possible

My Code - doDeepLookup actually is a API call, but for the sake of argument lets just say it appends some text in-front of the read line from the while loop

```
#!/bin/bash
n=0
maxjobs=20

resultsArray=""
while IFS= read -r line
        do
        IPaddress="$(echo $line | sed 's/ /\n/g' | grep -E -o "([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}")"
        doDeepLookup "$line" "$IPaddress" &
        if(( $(($((++n)) % $maxjobs)) == 0 )) ; then
                wait
        fi
        done <<< "$(printf '%s\n' "${SomeOtherArray[@]}")"
        printf '%s\n' "${resultsArray[@]}" #Returns NULL

doDeepLookup() {
   results="$(echo "help me : $line")"
   resultsArray+=($results)
}
```

Comment: Look into [GNU Parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gnu-parallel?tab=Votes) for help parallelizing your bash script.

Comment: The parallel/multi-threading portion is working just fine. I am more concerned getting  values out without having to write to file. But I will check again to see if anyone has answered this concern

Comment: Don't write to a file.  Write to stdout.  Invoke the while loop with `resultsArray=( $(function-that-invokes-the-loop ))`

Comment: @WilliamPursell that did the trick! :)

Comment: Do you want to answer the question so I can accept it? If not I can answer my own question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to William

```
#!/bin/bash
n=0
maxjobs=20


WhileLoopFunction() {
    resultsArray=""
    while IFS= read -r line
        do
        IPaddress="$(echo $line | sed 's/ /\n/g' | grep -E -o "([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}")"
        doDeepLookup "$line" "$IPaddress" &
        if(( $(($((++n)) % $maxjobs)) == 0 )) ; then
                wait
        fi
        done <<< "$(printf '%s\n' "${SomeOtherArray[@]}")"
}

doDeepLookup() {
   results="$(echo "help me : $line")"
   echo $results
}

resultsArray=( $(WhileLoopFunction"${DeepArray[@]}") )
printf '%s\n' "${resultsArray[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

With `parset` from GNU Parallel you would do something like:

```
parset resultsArray doDeepLookup ::: "${DeepArray[@]}" 
printf '%s\n' "${resultsArray[@]}"
```